# How can I use "git add --patch" in PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm, patch

I am in the process of migrating our old environment from SVN + eclipse to Git + PhpStorm. I read many tutorials about Git and just recently found the `git add --patch` command. Is it possible to use it in PhpStorm through the GUI?

I already tried to do it manually using a terminal window inside of PhpStorm, but when I than use the `VCS | Commit Changes` window, it will just add the rest of the lines to the staging area and commit all hunks.

Comment: Are you looking for `VCS | Create Patch ...`?

Comment: No. I am looking for a way to only put some changes (hunks) in a file to the index (aka. staging area) and commit only those changes. Using `VCS | Create Patch ...` I can only create a .diff file with ALL changes from selected files. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it is not available: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201

Please follow that ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually some progress, the feature you mentioned is now in the EAP release.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more